Выдать перечень книг, имеющихся в наличии, указав их количество, цену. SQL
Задача: Выдать перечень книг, имеющихся в наличии, указав их количество, цену
Проблема в использовании подзапроса, а именно где его нужно использовать и как? Как убрать дублирование записей и найти общую для записи разность сумм двух таблиц?
Даны таблицы 4 таблицы (1 не нужна для решения задачи):
BooksArrive - IdBookArrive, IdKnowledgeArea, CatalogIndex, Count, ArriveDate
BooksSales - IdSale, IdKnowledgeArea, CatalogIndex, Count, SellingPrice, SellDate
Books - CatalogIndex, IdKnowledgeArea, Authors, Name, ReleaseDate, Cost
Select b.Name, b.Cost, (ba."Count" - SUM(bs."Count")) as Remain
From BooksSales as bs, Books as b, BooksArrive as ba
Where (bs.CatalogIndex = b.CatalogIndex) AND (ba.CatalogIndex = b.CatalogIndex) AND ((ba."Count" - bs."Count") > 0)
GROUP BY b.Name,  b.Cost, ba."Count"





А почему вы группируете по значению ba."Count", а не суммируете его, как bs."Count"? Судя по значениям в таблицах, с прибытием книг всё тоже самое, что и с продажами - книги там могут повторяться, их количество нужно суммировать.

но это для примера, поскольку так виднее будет в запросе ошибку

иначе была бы одна запись и пересчитывать не каждый стал бы, тут всё же в примере главное, что на одну книгу с каждым разным завозом данного товара находиться разность от суммы продаж

Я только не очень понимаю, что с ценой продажи. Если книга продавалась по разной цене, то какую цену вы должны выводить? Последнюю? Ну вот разве что для этого может быть нужен подзапрос.

с ценой продажи нужно выбрать общую для всех, по видимому в первой строке опечатка, извиняюсь

Общую для всех цену - это как? Средне-взвешенную по всем продажам данной книги?

общая не меняется никогда, поэтому она одинаковая для всех

И про количество я так и не понял вашу мысль. Книгу несколько раз завозили, несколько раз продавали. Причём, её могли одинаковыми партиями завозить, а могли разными. Что вы пытаетесь посчитать, группируя по количеству в завезённой партии - непонятно. Хотите разделить разные завозы книги - группируйте по id завоза. Иначе получится мешанина, где-то сгруппируется, где-то нет.

а как тогда надо правильно? Если отойти строго к задаче. Возможно мой код абсолютно неправильный, поэтому прошу решите как надо.

Посмотрите таблицу продаж, первые две строки. Одна и та же книга, две разные цены. Что с этим предполагается делать? В общем, задача, мягко говоря, недоформулирована. Прежде чем писать код, нужно чётко поставить ТЗ, расписав что на входе, что на выходе, и как это вот на выходе получается, по какому алгоритму.

я просто хочу посчитать правильно разницу между итоговым поступившим количеством товара и итоговым проданным количеством товара

Разница между поступившим и проданным - сумма поступившего минус сумма проданного. Группировка по CatalogIndex в идеале. Имя и цена могут совпасть у разных книг, эти поля поэтому лучше потом джойнить отдельно.

а как собственно сделать этот запрос? Поскольку на словах понятно, а как реализовать в коде вообще нет.

Ну я дал примерный ответ. Только с ценой не знаю, выбрать последнюю проще всего через оконную функцию, наверное, но не уверен, что вы их проходили. А через другие способы как-то сложновато будет, наверное

Не совсем ещё ответ, поскольку задача так и не сформулирована чётко, но руководство к действию:
SELECT bb.Name, r.Remain 
FROM Books bb
JOIN (SELECT b.CatalogIndex, 
       SUM(ISNULL(ba."Count", 0)) - SUM(ISNULL(bs."Count", 0)) as Remain
      FROM Books as b
      LEFT JOIN BooksArrive as ba ON ba.CatalogIndex = b.CatalogIndex
      LEFT JOIN BooksSales  as bs ON bs.CatalogIndex = b.CatalogIndex
      GROUP BY b.CatalogIndex
) r ON r.CatalogIndex = bb.CatalogIndex

Суть:

Группируем книги только по CatalogIndex, по количеству не нужно, а название и цена теоретически могут совпасть у разных книг
Соединять таблицы лучше через JOIN ... ON, так гораздо нагляднее
Опять же LEFT JOIN + ISNULL позволят правильно обработать ситуацию, когда по каким-то книгам не было завоза или продаж

Последнюю цену продажи можно получить отдельным подзапросом либо с использованием оконной функции, либо сгруппировать продажи по книгам, взять максимальный id продажи по каждой группе, потом присоединить продажи с этими id и взять из них цену продажи. Возможно, это как-то проще делается, я так сходу не соображу.

я использую delphi 7 в котором увы нет таких возможностей для использования Select, имеется возможность использования IN, All, ... . Но так стало в разы понятнее, за что спасибо

(delphi 7 + бд interbase, о которой наверняка уже никто не помнит)

Не уверен, что можно обойтись одним IN в данном случае )

я в этом тоже абсолютно уверен, но вузовские преподаватели дали эту задачу даже не объяснив JOIN )

Ну, строгий JOIN можно заменить как у вас перечислением таблиц во FROM, но LEFT JOIN уже не заменишь, ну и, повторюсь, джойнить таблицы через ON гораздо понятнее, чем с одним WHERE, в котором все условия скопом лежат. Возможно, у вас гарантированы записи для каждой книге в обеих таблицах и LEFT JOIN не нужен, но как-то это не универсально.

понятно, огромное спасибо за решение проблемы
